# ssrs Sum many textbox value in footer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

Greeting
i have 3 textbox value in footer of my report
i want make total (sum) for tow of them
so when i try to make total with them give me this error

```html
The Value expression for the textrun ‘.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ refers to more than one report item. An expression in a page header or footer can refer to only one report item.
```

i used those code for sum but none of them working

```
=ReportItems!Textbox62.Value+ReportItems!Textbox61.Value
```

and this

```
=CDec(ReportItems!Textbox62.Value)+CDec(ReportItems!Textbox61.Value)
```

is there any idea fro solve this problem

Comment: Is either textbox set up in a detail row where multiple rows and values can print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends how your textbox expressions are. Lets assume you have one dataset (`Dataset1`) then you have

```
'Textbox1
=Sum(Fields!SomeNumericValue.Value)

'Textbox2
=Avg(Fields!SomeOtherNumericValue.Value)
```

Then this will work for your other textbox:

```
 'Textbox3
 =ReportItems!Textbox1.Value + ReportItems!Textbox2.Value 
 =Sum(Fields!SomeNumericValue.Value) + Avg(Fields!SomeOtherNumericValue.Value)
```

If you have two datasets (`Dataset1` and `Dataset2`) this will work:

```
'Textbox1
=Sum(Fields!NumericValue1.Value, "Dataset1")

'Textbox2
=Avg(Fields!NumericValue2.Value, "Dataset2")

'Textbox2
=Sum(Fields!NumericValue1.Value, "Dataset1") + Avg(Fields!NumericValue2.Value, "Dataset2")
```

Comment: should i type 'Textbox1 before expression?

Comment: No this is just an information from myself and indicates the name of the textbox we are talking about